# Is it possible to remap the PWM output to other pins?

Tags: arduino, pwm, pcb

The Arduino Uno has PWM outputs on pins `11`, `10`, `9`, `6`, `5`, and `3`. Is it possible to remap the PWM outputs from these pins to other pins ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in a fashion. The PWM pins are defined by the microcontroller hardware, which is something that can't be messed with easily (not via software, at any rate).

---

You can, of course, scratch out some of the tracks on the board and add your own, but this is a rather icky solution, and you may end up irreversibly damaging your board<sup>1</sup>.

---

A better solution is to make a shield that remaps the pins. This is not too hard: You first get a perfboard and some male/female header strips of the appropriate size. Now, you solder the male headers on, aligned with the Arduino. Then, solder the female bergs onto the opposite side of the perfboard -- stagger them, but make sure that they are spaced out the same as on an Arduino. Finally, do whatever cross-connections you want. Note that you will need to [offset the header strips](http://brettbeauregard.com/blog/2009/07/arduino-offset-header/)

---

If the reason you want to remap the pins is because some code you use assumes PWM on the wrong pins, then simply create a method `transform()` that takes in a pin number and maps it to another (use a [switch case statement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm)). Then, replace (most IDEs have a find/replace function) all the digital/analog read/write methods with a new set of functions, for example:

```
void digitalWrite2(int pin, int val){
 digitalWrite(transform(pin),val);
}
```

---

And, finally, you can use the [SoftPWM Library](https://code.google.com/p/rogue-code/wiki/SoftPWMLibraryDocumentation) for software PWM on all pins. This may not be the exact same as hardware PWM (different pulse characteristics, may make your application slow), but it it's a viable option.

<sup>1. Well, you *are* irreversibly damaging it either way, but there is a chance you may scratch out too many things and you won't be able to put the board back to even semi-working conditions. Messing directly with the board is not advisable unless you know what you're doing.</sup>

Comment: Actually, you [cannot make a shield using standard perfboard](http://brettbeauregard.com/blog/2009/07/arduino-offset-header/): The separation between the two blocks of pin headers on the "Digital" side of the classic Arduino (Uno, Mega etc) is 0.16 inches, **not a multiple of 0.1 inches**, a decision that might have been made to sell more shields and make home-made shields inconvenient to produce. The official story says that this was an error, but I see that as unlikely to have propagated for years unless intentional. The Nano, Pro Mini etc do not have this issue.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh One benefit of the mis-matched spacing is that it prevents someone from plugging in a shield backwards.  This may seem like a minor thing but as the Arduino community has grown, this has been become important.  (e.g. I've seen a picture of someone plugging USB into an Ethernet port on the official Forums, asking why it won't work.)

Comment: @JamesC4S Oddly that's never been a [reason given by the official spokespersons](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,22737.0.html#13). If they'd thought of it, they could have pulled a win out of this, instead of admitting they goofed up: "*I made that mistake, when I made the first arduino board.
 ... We had 5 minutes before the deadline to go into production, the PCB  guy was on the phone ...*". The two pin rows have different pin counts anyway, not that that would prevent an enterprising person from shoving a shield in.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Actually, that's where I picked it up.  The official FAQ use to have the "eleventh hour mistake" excuse.  When the current site designed launch, it had the "backwards" excuse.  Now there's no mention of it.  Personally, I like to stick with the backwards one because it actually makes a little bit of sense.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is done on the hardware of the chip, I have seen software PWM libraries but they don't work as well as the hardware version and tie up the micro while doing it.

http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,19451.0.html